# get current jre's file path

Tags: java, filepath

Suppose we have two java applications A and B. Application A will call application B.
Application A has started, however when A calls B, I don't know the java_home or any other jre path, I want to get which jre application A is run on, return the jre's execution file's path, is this possible?

Comment: *"..however when A calls B"*  Calls it what?  By that statement, do you mean that A & B are communicating?  If so, what does that have to do with the paths of the JREs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the installation directory for the JRE by requesting the system propertie `java.home`:

```
String jrePath = System.getProperty("java.home");
```

More on System Properties [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Comment: Oh my god! we posted same response. I may remove mine.

Comment: I'm a bit astonished, too. That is almost the exact same response :D

Comment: This will only work if you're using the system jre. What about when you're using a custom jre?

Comment: @Christo could you clarify why it wouldn't work? It should work irrelevant of jre used. It doesn't depend on JAVA_HOME in any way.