# How TOMCAT locates JRE in system?

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat

Just now I updated my tomcat to tomcat8. I wondered how it is finding the JRE path in the system.?

Does anybody know,

### **how I can know the path of JRE through the java code?**

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176603/get-current-jres-file-path ?

Comment: have you tried, say, looking at the startup scripts?

Comment: which is your question actually, how dows tomcat locate JRE, or how would you be able to find it through java code?

Comment: @eis both are my Questions, if I get answer for first, then it'll be directly ans for my second question.

Comment: @YsrShk no, the questions are totally different. Tomcat doesn't find it out through java code, it finds it out through system variables.

Comment: @eis
even the duplicate suggested by mfrankli, suggests that it is using SYSTEM VAR, if it is not java, then what it is? that will be my Question, **P.S. :I assumed that tomcat uses java .** n what if I had not set the path of java_home, still it finds.???

Comment: @YsrShk no, it doesn't. The post suggests using `java.home`. JAVA_HOME is an environment variable, but it's totally unrelated to `java.home`. Please be specific. Tomcat uses batch scripts when starting up, it uses java internally, but not for starting.

Comment: okkey fine, thanks for the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It knows it by checking the JAVA_HOME environment variable.